# How to set summary footer caption row and summary values in same row in ultragrid

Tags: c#, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I am evaluating UltraGrid control for my windows forms application. I observed that the summary row is displayed separately and value obtained from formula is displayed on a separate row.

Does anyone know how to merge these 2 rows.
For e.g.
SubTotal  value1   value2   value3

Thanks,
Vijay

Comment: Do you have a picture that you could annotate with details on what you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it is possible. One problem could be to choose under which column  to put the caption text, what if the user move the column? what if the caption spans more than one column?

A possible workaround could be to define a Custom Summary and set an empty string as return value of the calculation, then use the DisplayFormat property to set the text to be used as caption.

```
SummarySettings ss = grid.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Summaries.Add("SummaryKeyName", 
                     SummaryType.Custom, new FakeCaptionSummary(), 
                     grid.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns["ColumnUsedForCaption"],  
                     SummaryPosition.UseSummaryPositionColumn, 
                     grid.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns["ColumnUsedForCaption"]);
ss.DisplayFormat = "Subtotals";
```

then build a class that implements the `ICustomSummaryCalculator` interface

```
internal class FakeCaptionSummary : ICustomSummaryCalculator
{
    public FakeCaptionSummary()
    {
         // Empty constructor
    }
    // Called at the start of the custom summary calculation
    public void BeginCustomSummary(SummarySettings summarySettings, RowsCollection rows)
    {}
    // Called for each row in band of this summary
    public void AggregateCustomSummary(SummarySettings summarySettings, UltraGridRow row)
    {}
    // Called to get the return value to put in the SummaryRpw at the specified column
    public object EndCustomSummary(SummarySettings summarySettings, RowsCollection rows)
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

keep in mind however that this solution has all the drawbacks that I have outlined at the start of this answer.